# SSIS foreach loop xlsx files

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Hello I see similar questions has been ask before but I am having a bit of trouble with this issue, this is using excel 2013 data files and sql server 2012.

I have a foreach loop container

This for each has a enumerator of "Foreach file enumerator" for "*.xlsx"

On the Data Flow

In the ExcelFilePath I have a base file path

And in the Expression the one of the foreach loop, but if the base file is missing the package fail, unless it finds this starting "point". what I am doing wrong?.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before and have used 2 different approaches.
If the process should only run if files exist, I've written a c# script to set a flag 'DataExists' so I can evaluate and take different paths within the SSIS package.  The other is I have a dummy file on the directory and when I build the expression in the foreach container I use variables that will use that dummy file name/location if nothing else exists.   Hope that helps.

Comment: I will take in consideration your C# approach at the moment I did a dummy file as you suggest.